# Azure shared dashboard is not be updated

Tags: azure, dashboard, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer

I have such a query:

```
let start=datetime("2019-06-22T01:44:00.000");
let end=datetime("2019-06-22T07:44:00.000");
let timeGrain=5m;
let dataset1= requests
| where timestamp > start and timestamp < end ;
dataset1
| summarize Gesamt=sum(itemCount) , Durchschnittsdauer=round(avg(duration /1000),2), Instanz=dcount(cloud_RoleInstance)  by  Funktionsname=name
| join kind= inner 
(
exceptions
| where timestamp > start and timestamp < end 
| summarize Fehler=count() by Funktionsname=operation_Name
) on Funktionsname
| project Funktionsname ,Gesamt , Erfolgreich=Gesamt - Fehler, Fehler, Durchschnittsdauer
```

If I test it in Application insight query manager, I get data. But after I pin it to the share dashboard, and changing the Time (local and UTC) the dashboard shows me no results. Do you know how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it
I should change starttime and endtime to:

```
let start=datetime("2019-06-24 13:44:00.000Z");
let end=datetime("2019-06-24 19:44:00.000Z");
```